# On Hover Div Issue and Vertically Center Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with vertically centering the main text and I want to slide up the main Lorem Ipsum text on hover and then reveal / change color of the subtext. Please help me with this.

image for reference : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQlbd.jpg

Code :

```
<section id="contact" class="map-top">
    <div class="row map-text">
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui </p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p> </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.map-top{
  background: gray;
  width:100%;
}

.border-right{
border-right: 1px solid;
line-height: 100px;
border-right-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.33);

}
.map-text{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "ProximaNova-Bold";
  }

.t-text{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  color: transparent;
}

.t-text:hover{
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Merriweather_light";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tk0waoku/1/

Comment: So, you want to slide up "Neque porro quisquam est qui" text when you hover. is that you want ?

Comment: @Maharshi You are right, I  want the "Lorem Ipsum" to be vertically centered in the div and when i hover on it, it should slide up and the "Neque porro quisquam est qui" part should reveal.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tk0waoku/2/

Comment: @ChrisHappy thumb up for it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v8vo351w/

Comment: Thanks Chris, However the "Neque porro quisquam est qui" does not show when i hover on "lorem ipsum", it only shows up when i hover on the sub text and "lorem ipsum" is still not centered vertically. @ChrisHappy

Comment: @Zees see my updated solution

Answer (score 1):

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk0waoku/3/)

```css
.map-top {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}

.border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-right-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.33);
}

.map-text {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "ProximaNova-Bold";
}

.col-md-3 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-md-3 > span {
  width: 100%;
}

.t-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  color: transparent;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  transition: transform .4s;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.hover-e:hover > .t-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Merriweather_light";
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<section id="contact" class="map-top">
  <div class="row map-text">
    <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e"><span>Lorem Ipsum </span>
      <p class="t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e"><span>Lorem Ipsum </span>
      <p class="t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e"><span>Lorem Ipsum </span>
      <p class="t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e"><span>Lorem Ipsum </span>
      <p class="t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e"><span>Lorem Ipsum </span>
      <p class="t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes

```css
.map-top{
  background: gray;
  width:100%;
}

.border-right{
border-right: 1px solid;
line-height: 100px;
border-right-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.33);

}
.map-text{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "ProximaNova-Bold";
  }
div.hover-e .t-text
{
  transform: translateY(50px);
  transition: transform .4s;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  color: transparent;
}
div.hover-e:hover .t-text {
  transform: translateY(0);
   margin-top: -30px;
   font-size: 16px;
  color: white !important;
  font-family: "Merriweather_light";
}
```

```html
<section id="contact" class="map-top">
    <div class="row map-text">
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui </p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right hover-e">Lorem Ipsum <p class= "t-text">Neque porro quisquam est qui</p> </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think he would like the "main text" to be vertically centered as well.